# RestAssured JsonPath: Issue with getting data from json

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I need to take a data from json file which has a weird structure and i can't find a solution for it. I'm using restAssured with jsonPath 
and when i'm trying to get data for particular week like this

```
getJsonPath().getList("years.2017.weeks.find{it.isoWeekNum == '1'}")
```

i'm getting an error

```
Invalid JSON expression: Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: 2017 @ line 1, column 33.
 years.2017.weeks.find{it.isoWeekNum == '1'}
```

At the same time i can get data with this expression

`getJsonPath().getList("years.2017.weeks")`

which returns to me the all list of weeks.

The only way that i found to get what i need is like this

`getJsonPath().getList("years[1]['2017'].weeks.find{it.isoWeekNum == '1'}")`

But this is not what i'm looking for. I need to find a solution where i can get data without years[1] for 2017 and years[0] for 2016

```
 "{
  "years": [
    {
      "2016": {
        "currentIsoWeek": "49",
        "currentTourWeek": "49",
        "weeks": [
          {
            "isoWeekNum": "1",
            "tourWeekNum": "1",
            "categories": []
          },
          {
            "isoWeekNum": "2",
            "tourWeekNum": "2",
            "categories": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "2017": {
        "currentIsoWeek": "",
        "currentTourWeek": "",
        "weeks": [
          {
            "isoWeekNum": "1",
            "tourWeekNum": "1",
            "categories": []
          },
          {
            "isoWeekNum": "2",
            "tourWeekNum": "2",
            "categories": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope the following code is exactly what are you looking for:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(yourJson).using(new JsonPathConfig("UTF-8"));

    System.out.println(
            jsonPath.get("years['2017'].weeks*.find {it.isoWeekNum == '1'}")
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i have been on this issue for a long time and finally i got a solution.